# Store reference of an ushort in an array in c#

Tags: c#, reference

I would like to store reference of an `ushort` variable in an `ushort array`, so that the value of the variable changes when I change the values inside the ushort array. Here is my sample code which will give a clear picture of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
public void IndexSetter(List<int> indexVal,Rootobject objectVal)
{
    ushort[] refereneArray = new ushort[8] 
    {
        objectVal.index1, objectVal.index2, 
        objectVal.index3 , objectVal.index4,
        objectVal.index5, objectVal.index6, 
        objectVal.index7, objectVal.index8 
    };
    for(int j = 0; j< indexVal.Count;j++)
    {
        refereneArray[j] =(ushort) indexVal[j];
    }  
}
```

Instead of storing the values like from above code , I need to store the reference so that the changes in `indexVal` list reflect in the values of index1, index2.. etc

Comment: This is not possible. `ushort` is not a reference type, but a value type. Why don't you just store a reference to `Rootobject` anway? (I assume it's a class)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Array of references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472278/c-sharp-array-of-references)

Comment: @adjan Thanks ..Yes. Rootobject is a class. And I need only these index values as references. Since I never worked with setting references, I am not sure how to store reference to Rootobject . Could you give me an insight on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´d suggest not to have 8 indexes with the exact same name (except a number). Give every member of your class a name describing what it´s ment to be, however `index6` isn´t really self-explanatory.

Having said this what you can do is to have one array of indexes within your class itself:

```
class Rootobject
{
    public int[] Indexes { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can access them as follows:

```
public void IndexSetter(List<int> indexVal, Rootobject objectVal)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < indexVal.Count; i++)
        objectVal.Indexes[index] = indexVal[i];
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
objectVal.Indexes = indexVal.Cast<ushort>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with unsafe code, using array of pointers like this:

```
static unsafe void IndexSetter(IList<ushort> indexVal, Rootobject objectVal) {
    fixed (ushort* r1 = &objectVal.index1)
    fixed (ushort* r2 = &objectVal.index2) {
        ushort*[] refereneArray = {r1, r2};
        for (int j = 0; j < indexVal.Count; j++) {
            *refereneArray[j] = (ushort) indexVal[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Should you really do this in real application is another story. There is very high chance that there is a better way to solve your problem, but you didn't tell us what the actual problem is.

If perfomance is not critical - you can use reflection:

```
static void IndexSetter2(IList<ushort> indexVal, Rootobject objectVal) {
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var field in objectVal.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                         .Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("index") && c.FieldType == typeof(ushort))
                         .OrderBy(c => c.Name)) {
        field.SetValue(objectVal, indexVal[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But I dont have any problem. I have set of values inside indexVal list which gets generated dynamically according to a json file input. Once I parse the json I need to take the values of the index from json(number of index values is a variable, it can be 2 or 3 , or all 8). I need to write a code which takes the values from indexVal list and set it to the ushort index variables from Rootobject Class. is there a better way to do this.?

Comment: If perfomance is not super critical - you can enumerate fields in Rootobject with reflection and set values directly (without array).

Comment: You mean like doing a shallow copy of the variables?

Comment: I've updated answer with reflection way. But if possible - better use solution from other answer.