# I can't see the labels text's. What should I do?

Tags: c#, winforms

**I can't see the labels text's. What should I do?**

[image]

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        Random rnd = new Random();
        string[] Maths = { "Add", "Subtract", "Multiply" };
        int[] total = new int[5];
        int score = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetUpGame();
        }

        private void SetUpGame()
        {
            string[] seq_Left = { lblNum1Left.Text, lblNum2Left.Text, lblNum3Left.Text, lblNum4Left.Text, lblNum5Left.Text };
            string[] seq_Right = { lblNum1Right.Text, lblNum2Right.Text, lblNum3Right.Text, lblNum4Right.Text, lblNum5Right.Text };
            string[] seq_Symbol = { lblSymbol1.Text, lblSymbol2.Text, lblSymbol3.Text, lblSymbol4.Text, lblSymbol5.Text };
            string[] seq_Answer = { txtAnswer1.Text, txtAnswer2.Text, txtAnswer3.Text, txtAnswer4.Text, txtAnswer5.Text };

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                int numA = rnd.Next(10, 20);
                int numB = rnd.Next(0, 9);

                seq_Answer[i] = "";

                switch (Maths[rnd.Next(0, Maths.Length)])
                {
                    case "Add":
                        total[i] = numA + numB;
                        seq_Symbol[i] = "+";
                        break;

                    case "Subtract":
                        total[i] = numA - numB;
                        seq_Symbol[i] = "-";
                        break;

                    case "Multiply":
                        total[i] = numA * numB;
                        seq_Symbol[i] = "x";
                        break;
                }

                seq_Left[i] = numA.ToString();
                seq_Right[i] = numB.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

In the last rows I convert nums to string and assign to texts. So I should see the texts but I didn't. If I don't use seq[] the code will be too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the last rows I convert nums to string and assign to texts.

No, you absolutely do not. You never assign anything to the `Text` of any `Label`. Here:

```cs
string[] seq_Left = { lblNum1Left.Text, lblNum2Left.Text, lblNum3Left.Text, lblNum4Left.Text, lblNum5Left.Text };
```

You are getting the `Text` of each `Label` and putting it in a `string` array. That array just contains `strings`. It knows nothing about the `Labels` that those `strings` came from. That would be equivalent to this:

```cs
string str1 = lblNum1Left.Text;
// ...
string str5 = lblNum5Left.Text;

string[] seq_Left = { str1, str2, str3, str4, str5 };
```

Hopefully that makes it obvious why there's no such connection. Here:

```cs
seq_Left[i] = numA.ToString();
```

you're simply putting a `string` into the array, replacing the `string` that was there. The array knows nothing about any `Labels` so how could it affect them?

What you would need to do would be to create an array that actually contains the `Labels`:

```cs
Label[] seq_Left = { lblNum1Left, lblNum2Left, lblNum3Left, lblNum4Left, lblNum5Left };
```

and then set the `Text` of those `Labels`:

```cs
seq_Left[i].Text = numA.ToString();
```

Comment: and in case someone was wondering if you could create a array of references: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472278